Pydantic 2.7 date_from_datetime_parsing error
I have a model in pydantic in the following format:
class CommonResponse(_BaseSchema):
    """ Schema com os campos padrões dos objetos response """
    legal_nature: str | None = Field(default=None, alias='legalNature')
    amount: float | None = Field(default=None, alias='amount')
    occurrence_date: date | None = Field(default=None, alias='occurrenceDate')
    message: str | None = Field(default=None, alias='message')
    place: str | None = Field(default=None, alias='place')
    district: str | None = Field(default=None, alias='district')
    civil_court: str | None = Field(default=None, alias='civilCourt')
    date_procedure: datetime | None = Field(default=None, alias='dateProcedure')
    number_procedure: str | None = Field(default=None, alias='numberProcedure')

The _BaseSchema class has a validator that converts dates in string format to date
...more code here...
    @field_validator('*', mode='before')
    def convert_str_to_date(cls, v:str, info: FieldValidationInfo) -> datetime.date:
        """" Convertendo de string para date, porém, apenas as notações BR """

        if v and info.mode == date and isinstance(v, str):
            # A serasa envia algumas datas inválidas
            if v == '00/00/0000' or v == '00000000':
                return None
            else:
                try:
                    return datetime.strptime(v, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
                except ValueError:
                    try:
                        return datetime.strptime(v[:10], '%Y-%m-%d').date()
                    except ValueError:
                        pass
        return v

Some dates are converted, but others I have the error:
  Input should be a valid date or datetime, invalid character in year [type=date_from_datetime_parsing, input_value='14/12/2023', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/date_from_datetime_parsing

I do not understand why. Can anybody help me?

I assume the purpose of using the info.mode == date condition is to filter date fields, but it definitely doesn't do what is expected.
For date fields it's calculated to False so this is equivalent to the following code which is expectedly raises ValidationError:
class CommonResponse(BaseModel):
    date_field: date | None

CommonResponse(date_field="14/12/2023") # raise ValidationError

I'd recommend explicitly specifying the fields you want to validate in field_validator and probably create more validators if necessary:
@field_validator("occurrence_date", "another_date", ...)

